# Translating numbers into Morse code and english text

Tags: c++

I tried to add numbers for English text string array and Morse code array but for English to Mosre it only translated 2 numbers into Morse when I typed 3 numbers in English text. For Morse to English text translation, the numbers in Morse translated to random symbols.

How can I solve this?

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <sstream>
 
using namespace std;
 
string convertToEnglish(string morse, string const morseCode[], string const alpha[]);
string convertToMorse(string english, string const morseCode[], string const alpha[]);
 
int main()
{
    string option = ""; 
    cout << "TEXT TO MORSE CODE or MORSE CODE TO TEXT Please selection option: \nSelect 1 to decode 
    English text to Morse code \nSelect 2 to decode Morse code to English text \n";
    getline(cin, option);
 
    string const morseCode[] = {".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.",
    "--.", "....", "..", ".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.", "---", ".--.", "--.-",
    ".-.", "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--..",".----","..---","...--"," "," "}; 
 
    string const englishLetter[] = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", 
    "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", 
    "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z","1","2","3",""," "}; 
 
 
    if (option == "1") 
    {
        //english to morse
 
        string input = ""; 
        cout << "Enter English words to translate, with a space between letters and three spaces between 
        words:";
        getline(cin, input);
 
        //Convert string to be all upper case
        string uppercaseInput = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++)
        {
            uppercaseInput += toupper(input[i]);
        }
 
        cout << convertToMorse(uppercaseInput, morseCode, englishLetter) << endl;
 
    } 
    else if (option == "2")
    {
        //morse to english
        string input = "";
        cout << "Enter morse with only space between code: \n";
        getline(cin, input);
        cout << convertToEnglish(input, morseCode, englishLetter) << endl;
    }
 
    return 0;
}
 
string convertToMorse(string english, string const morseCode[], string const alpha[]) 
{
    string output = "";
    string currentLetter = "";
 
    int position = 0;
 
    int const letterCount = english.length(); 
 
    int const numberOfAlpha = 28;
 
    cout << "\n";
 
    while (position <= letterCount)
    {
        currentLetter = string(1, english[position]); 
 
        int marker = 0;
 
        string addition = "";
 
        while (marker < 28)
        {           
            if (currentLetter == alpha[marker])
            {
                addition = morseCode[marker];
            }
 
            ++marker;
        }
 
        output += addition + " ";
 
        ++position;
    }
 
    return output;
}
 
string convertToEnglish(string morse, string const morseCode[], string const alpha[]) 
{
    string output = "";
    string currentLetter = "";
    istringstream ss(morse);    
 
    int const characters = 28;
 
    while(ss >> currentLetter)
    {
 
        int index = 0;
        while(currentLetter != morseCode[index] && index < characters)
        {
            ++index; //increment here so we don't have to decrement after the loop like if we put in the condition
        }
 
        output += 'A' + index;
    }
 
    return output;
}
```

Comment: remove the second last entry from both arrays

Comment: What were the inputs that you provided?

Comment: IMO your `convertToMorse` function is overly complex.  It should be around 5 lines of code.  Why is there a doubly-nested loop?

Comment: A good idea would be to use a map<string, string>, it'd make your code simpler.

Comment: A `std::unordered_map<char, string>` for english-to-morse, and `std::unordered_map<string, char>` for morse to english.  That would literally be no more than 3 or 4 lines of code for each function if those were used.  Also, is the issue with your input, or with the actual workings of the conversion functions?  You should put together a simple `main` program without all of those input statements and use hard-coded test data to test to see if the issue with the conversion functions.

Comment: The english to morse part runs ok in my test run. I dodn't encounter hat you described. The morse to english has error from operator+=. You have to add a c-casting into char: (char)('A' + index);.

Comment: But there is one error in Morse to English: the space is not proper interpret from Morse code to English. It is because you are using istream to currentletter. The operator>> takes all space as delimiters. Therefore, that makes it impossible to input space in Mores to English. In the other one (English to Morse), you are reading each element of the string, avoid such problem.